# Heroku CNAME redirect leads to www.www

Tags: redirects, url, heroku

I'm trying to use a domain name I have on Namecheap with Heroku. Heroku's documentation advised a CNAME Alias. In the past, I've gotten other domains on the same service (Namecheap) to work with Heroku, but I can't get this domain to work. I followed Heroku's instructions and imitated the way the other domains are set up.

Using Namecheap's web tool, I changed "All Host Records". In that section, I have:

```
@ http://www.example.com URL Redirect
www example.herokuapp.com CNAME (Alias)
```

set up at the top of the page. In Heroku's app settings, I can see that www.example.com is a domain of example.herokuapp.com, which I configured with the command line.
When I go to www.example.com, however, I get

> The server at page "www.www.example.com/?from=@" is not responding".

Any ideas how to fix it? I already tried manually changing the DNS to Google's servers, as well as using just about every variation of my domain. The additional www and /?from=@ seems to be a clue, but I'm not sure what's causing it.

To be clear, my objective is running my Heroku app through www.example.com

Comment: CNAME is **not** a redirect. It is an alias. Any CNAME equates a sub-domain to a domain name though trickier associations can be made. When you use a CNAME you would point it to a domain name or sub-domain that resolves through ordinary means. I am confused by your question. Can you tells us more about the *tools* that you are using and the mechanics of what you are trying to do??

Comment: Are the edits sufficient?

Comment: A bit clearer. Typically, a CNAME is used to alias www to a domain name. It would be www.example.com -> example.com. What is important is to use the full sub-domain name and domain name (www.example.com) and not just the sub-domain name (www) assuming I am recalling correctly. So I would suggest trying to change the www in your second line in your example to a full sub-domain name/domain name specification. If that is not enough, try associating it to *your* domain name instead of your hosts domain name.

Comment: What do you mean by associating it to my domain name?

Comment: I was making an assumption that you had a domain name which may not be the case for what you are doing. Still somewhat confused as to whether you have a domain name that you registered or not. Sorry.

Comment: I own the domain name. Let's say it is "www.example.com". I also have a Heroku app which runs at "example.herokuapp.com". I want "www.example.com" to work as the Heroku app. I followed Heroku's instructions, which said to set a CNAME Alias for "www.example.com" to "example.herokuapp.com". When I try to go to "www.example.com", however, I get redirected to "www.www.example.com/?from=@" and get a server is not responding errror.

Comment: Okay. Much clearer. It might be my fault! ;-) Your example: *www example.herokuapp.com CNAME (Alias)* to me says that you associated www to example.herokuapp.com when I would expect to see www.example.com associated to example.herokuapp.com. It could be just the way they are displaying things. Are there other records that are not in this list that could be helpful?

Comment: Not that I can think of... I didn't change any other settings and it's configured the same way I configured my other sites (which are working).

Comment: I am out of ideas for the moment. I would have to think about this for a bit. There has to be something different even if it is tiny. DNS, while highly technical, is dead simple for the bulk of what we do and yet easy to goof-up by accident. We have all done it several times. ;-) Let me think about this for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has this issue come up, changing the DNS to v1 using Namecheap's online interface and then setting the "@" row to blank fixed the issue.